# Syntax error in a create function, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, syntax-error

So, below is the function i'm writing(in MySQL) and I get a syntax error at the last "RETURN" line (RETURN d_count). I'm sure it's some simple thing, but I can't figure it out. 
Thanks!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION dept_count (dept_name VARCHAR(20))
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE d_count INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) into d_count
    FROM instructor
    WHERE instructor.dept_name=dept_name
RETURN d_count;
END $$
```

Comment: You need a semicolon betweeh the query and `RETURN`.

Comment: EVERYTIME! thanks @Barmar you ROCK!

Answer (score 2):

You should separate `SELECT` and `RETURN` with semicolon `;` :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION dept_count (dept_name VARCHAR(20))
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE d_count INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) into d_count
    FROM instructor
    WHERE instructor.dept_name=dept_name;
    RETURN d_count;
END $$
```

Comment: so, SELECT count(*) into d_count;    and return d_count;

Comment: `WHERE instructor.dept_name=dept_name;`, he marked it for you. You don't put semicolons in between a statement such as `SELECT...FROM...WHERE`.

Comment: i see it now, i thought he was taking about a different spot. sorry, very new to sql, and i thought it would be odd to put a semi colon in that spot.